# How to change JPEG image's Camera Make & Model in PHP?

Tags: php, camera, metadata

I used PHP to create a 2:1 sized 360 image.
As I changed Camera Make & Model in File Manager on Windows 10, it could be Panorama 360 on Facebook.
Now I want to add those information into my output image automatically in PHP.
I searched so much but nothing worked for me.
Someone said on Internet that PHP_JPEG_Metadata_Toolkit_1.12 can help.
I downloaded it but I don't know how to use.
Please help me step by step because I am newbie and I learn by myself PHP.
Thank you so much!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Thank you, but that function is ReadOnly, I want to write my own information to those fields.